# Is there any way in Twig to determine if a method/parameter exists without putting ifs everywhere?

Tags: symfony, twig

When using Symfony2 and Twig together, if you need to do this:

```
<td>{{ myObject.method.parameter }}</td>
```

or just

```
<td>{{ myObject.parameter }}</td>
```

If what the twig file is trying to access is not set, an error will be thrown.
Is there a cleaner way to prevent this other than writing this everywhere:

```
<td>{% if myObject.method.parameter is defined %}{{ myObject.method.parameter }}{% endif %}</td>
```

It has been nice working with Angular recently, because it doesn't seem to care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pure Twig solution would be to use the `default` filter:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html

It looks like this and works fine for me:

```
{{ myObject.it.is.not.designed|default('it is not defined') }}
```

The default text can be an empty string `''`.

Now you have to set the default for every variable. Unlike `{% autoescape %}`, it seems a filter cannot be defined for a larger code area. In order to make it simple, I would create a macro:

```
{% macro safeEcho(value) %}
  {{ value | default('') }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Don't forget to import:

```
{% import _self as helper %}
```

Test:

```
Test:{{ helper.safeEcho(echolabels.something.something_2) }}
```

If I would use this very often, I'd consider short names, although I do not use abbreviations usually: `h.se()`

More about macros:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

If you need this fundamentally, there might be possibilities to overwrite the Twig lexer:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/internals.html

I don't know Twig as a part of Symfony2 well. It might be that its configuration offers an other option:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html

Finally, see here that this question was asked before with different answers.

[How to check for null in Twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264889/how-to-check-for-null-in-twig)

[symfony, twig - default filter for all variables in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851265/symfony-twig-default-filter-for-all-variables-in-template)

Maybe the Twig developers should consider offering a "general variable default" option :-)

Comment: Turns out that as Twig is open source, WE are the Twig developers...  *facepalm*